# Taking an array (or string) of terms, how do I efficiently go about removing common terms?

Tags: php, arrays

This is a somewhat ambiguous question and for that I do apologise.

I've got a large number of words which I'm taking from `$_POST` values using the following code:

```
$text2check = array();          

$fields = array( "etymology", "distribution", "habitat", "max_size", "aquarium_size", "maintenance", "water_chemistry", "diet",
    "behaviour", "dimorphism", "reproduction", "misc_notes" );

$fields = array( "distribution" );

foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if ( in_array( $key, $fields ) ) {
        $text2check = array_merge( $text2check, explode( " ", strip_tags( utf8_decode( $value ) ) ) );
    }
}
```

What I'm looking to do - with absolute maximum efficiency - is remove certain words:

- Duplicates
- Words below 4 characters
- Common terms...

Common terms is something I'm simply not familiar with. How do I determine a common word? Is it simply a case of hard-coding an array of common terms found on the internet and comparing against it?

When comparing arrays with arrays, what's the most efficient way of going about it?

---

**EDIT: Explanation**

The purpose behind this function is somewhat complex for me to explain. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053843/864245) answer, I'm trying to run a content filter which checks for certain terms then links them to other parts of my website. With huge amounts of words per post and huge amounts of potential links, I'm trying to do a pre-check before I run the filter, to cut down the number of links that I need to run the filter on.

As such, common terms are basically anything which appear quite regularly and certainly won't be linked; oft-used terms such as "sometimes", "obviously", etc.

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What its defining common terms? To me it could mean anything, loosely related terms, duplicates...you need an operational definition of common terms.

Comment: Do you have a specification you're working against? If not, then I guess you're free to come up with your own specification of common words, and use that. I guess there must be sites out there that list the most common words in English....

Comment: I'll update my OP with a definition of common terms, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For removing duplicates, array_unique() will do the trick.

Words below four characters, just loop through the array and check.

As far as common terms go, you could loop through the data and remove terms that occur more than X times, other than that I'd think you'd have to hard code them.